# Xamarin Forms Push Notification: Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter Error

Tags: xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add push Notifications to my application and I have added `xamarin.google.playservices.Gcm` package into my project and now I am getting the following error.

```
 Error XA5207: Please install package: 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter' available in SDK installer. Java library file /Users/xyz/.local/share/Xamarin/Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter/23.3.0.0/embedded/libs/internal_impl-23.3.0.jar doesn't exist. (XA5207) (NotificationExamplenew.Droid)
```

Comment: Right click the project -> go to Manage NuGet Packages -> click the `Installed` tab -> and look for `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter`, do you see it listed there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure , u don't add the these package manually , some time xamarin forms are not compatible with newest releases of android pkgs, 
simply remove all the package , and add Xamarin forms from nuget ,this will automatically download all the required dependency 
also make sure to install required packages , from tool-> android sdks manager -> select relevant listiings (extras in last).

I have succesfully implemented GCM based push notification let me know if u get stuck somewhere

Comment: Thanks for updating the information. If possible can u share u r code to my mail id(gudivada.rajyalaxmi@gmail.com).

Comment: I can't share client propriety , i can surely guide you , here is the link , which will give whole idea and code .
https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/RemoteNotifications/

Comment: Thanks for u r response. Even i followed  the same link. My problem is I didn't found Android support library in Extras(Android Sdk Manager) i am using xamarin studio in Mac OS.

Comment: what u didn't find which pkg? u need gcm support from nuget,rest all u might have already

Comment: yeah I did the same thing but i am getting the following error.Users/xyz/.local/share/Xamarin/Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter/23.3.0.0/embedded/libs/internal_impl-23.3.0.jar doesn't exist. (XA5207) (NotificationExamplenew.Droid)

Comment: clear the Xamarin folder , and cache from folder above it , compile it and run again , u will be able to build it

Comment: Now I am able to use notifications in my application using GCM. I just changed the working environment from Mac to Visual Studio 2015 and I followed the link which u gave. Thanks saket kumar

Answer (score 1):

1) Check MediaRouter NuGet package was added to you project and project References.[image]

2) Check Android SDK manager for latest update on our target SDK
[image]

And latest Support Library
[image]

Comment: Thanks for u r response. I didnt found Android support library in Extras(SDK Manager) i am using xamarin studio in Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have Android Support Library installed and still you get this error then the following solution might work.

I deleted the folder 23.3.0.0 from the folder C:\Users(UserName)\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter and rebuilt the project again to fix it.

Basically, Xamarin picks the right version from Android SDK and extracts files in the above mentioned folder.